# default Service Accounts for API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What service accounts are enabled by default by GCP once api is enabled?

For example I enable container.googleapis.com in my project, how do I know what SA were created and with what roles?

Thanks

Comment: Does @Serhii Rohoza’s explanation clarify your question? If yes, can you please accept and upvote the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

GCP works in a different way. Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#why_use_service_accounts):

> **Google Cloud Platform automatically creates a service account named "Compute Engine default service account" and GKE associates it with
>   the nodes it creates.** Depending on how your project is configured,
>   the default service account may or may not have permissions to use
>   other Cloud Platform APIs. GKE also assigns some limited [access
>   scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) to compute instances. Updating the default service
>   account's permissions or assigning more access scopes to compute
>   instances is not the recommended way to authenticate to other Cloud
>   Platform services from Pods running on GKE.
>
> **The recommended way to authenticate to Google Cloud Platform services from applications running on GKE is to create your own
>   [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)**. Ideally you must create a new service account
>   for each application that makes requests to Cloud Platform APIs.

You can find **more information about "Compute Engine default service account"** in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account):

> New projects come with the Compute Engine default service account,
>   identifiable using this email:
>
> ```
> [PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
> ```
>
> **Google creates the Compute Engine default service account and adds it to your project automatically but you have full control over the
>   account**.
>
> The Compute Engine default service account is created with the Cloud
>   IAM project editor role, but you can modify the service account's
>   roles to securely limit which Google APIs the service account can
>   access.
>
> **You can delete this service account from your project but doing so might cause any applications that depend on the service account's
>   credentials to fail.** If you accidentally delete the Compute Engine
>   default service account, you can try to recover the account within 30
>   days. For more information, see [Creating and managing service
>   accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account).

Also, please check article [Types of service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#types_of_service_accounts):

> **User-managed service accounts**
>
> **When you create a new Google Cloud project using the Cloud Console, if
>   the Compute Engine API is enabled for your project, a Compute Engine
>   service account is created for you by default.** It is identifiable
>   using the email:
>
> ```
> PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
> ```
>
> **If your project contains a App Engine application, the default App
>   Engine service account is created in your project by default.** It is
>   identifiable using the email:
>
> ```
> PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
> ```

**no other user-managed service accounts are created automatically**,

> If you create a service account in your project, you'll name the
>   service account and it will be assigned an email with the following
>   format:
>
> ```
> SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> ```
>
> **You can create up to 100 service accounts per project (including the default Compute Engine service account and the App Engine service
>   account) using the IAM API, the Cloud Console, or the gcloud
>   command-line tool**. These default service accounts and the service
>   accounts you explicitly create are the user-managed service accounts.

and

> **Google-managed service accounts**
>
> In addition to the user-managed service accounts, you might see some
>   additional service accounts in your project's IAM policy or in the
>   Cloud Console. These service accounts are created and owned by Google.
>   These accounts represent different Google services and each account is
>   automatically granted IAM roles to access your Google Cloud project.

**To create service accounts** please follow [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts) section [Creating a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating), for example:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create [SA-NAME] \
    --description "[SA-DESCRIPTION]" \
    --display-name "[SA-DISPLAY-NAME]"
```

**to check existing service accounts** please follow section [Listing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#listing), for example:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

In addition, please check [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart) for GKE.